# EXC_BAD_ACCESS using protocol composition

Tags: swift, protocols

I want to configure an object with multiple presentables; I've created protocols for them; so that I can combine them into a concrete presentable.

```
protocol Presentable {

}

protocol TextPresentable: Presentable {
    var text:String { get }
}

protocol ImagePresentable: Presentable {
    var image:String { get }
    var images:[String] { get }
}
```

The concrete struct:

```
struct ConcretePresentable: TextPresentable, ImagePresentable {
    var text:String { return "Text" }
    var image:String { return "Image" }
    var images:[String] { return ["A", "B"] }
}
```

The next thing would be to have a presenter, and I would check if the passed in presenter is actually valid:

```
typealias TextAndImagePresentable = protocol<TextPresentable, ImagePresentable>

struct ConcretePresenter {
    func configureWithPresentable(presentable: Presentable) {
        guard let textAndImagePresentable = presentable as? TextAndImagePresentable else {
            return
        }

        print(textAndImagePresentable.text)
        print(textAndImagePresentable.image)
        print(textAndImagePresentable.images)
    }
}
```

To configure:

```
    let concretePresentable = ConcretePresentable()
    let concretePresenter = ConcretePresenter()

    concretePresenter.configureWithPresentable(concretePresentable)
```

It goes fine if I run this in a playground, with all of the code in the same place. However, once I put this in a project and split it up into multiple files (`ConcretePresenter.swift`, `ConcretePresentable.swift` holding the concrete structs and `Presentable.swift` which holds the protocols), I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Why does that happen?

Comment: How is your project organized? Because I just tried pasting all your definitions in one file and the "To configure" part in another one and it works ok.

Comment: Updated the Question @EricD.

Comment: And indeed by dividing the files like you I get the same error now, on `print(textAndImagePresentable.images)`. Not sure why yet...

Comment: Indeed.  It should be clarified that this error is happening on the line trying to print the array.  The first two lines print fine.

Comment: actually it doesn't print the first two lines correctly when you get the error; the order is reversed.

Comment: Hmm, that's true.  But also, it should be noted that if you add an `Int` to the protocol, it doesn't print this value correctly at all.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ1ty.png Several issues here.  `image`'s string is printing in place of `text`, `text`'s string is printing in place of `image`.  It's not captured in the screenshot, but I added `value` as an `Int`... which should be 0, but is instead printing this big number.  And then checking from an array to a dictionary maintains the same error observer here.  My gut says, based off my `value` property and the problems with `image` and `text` that Swift is getting its memory addresses screwy here.

Comment: The more I think about this, the more I think it is potentially correct that this should not be allowed, and that potentially the real problem here is that Swift allows it to compile... I'm thinking about it... if I get to feeling more strongly this way, I'll update my answer to more fully explain that line of reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked about this on *Swift Users* and filled a bug.

Confirmed to be a bug in the compiler:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4477

Fixed by Joe Groff now:

> Joe Groff added a comment - 2 hours ago
>
> Merged. Should be fixed in future snapshots.

Answer (score 2):

As a disclaimer, I don't necessarily find this answer very satisfying, but it *does* work.

---

So, once I noticed that the text & image properties were being returned in each others places (the value for `text` is being returned by the `image` property and vice versa), I figured the problem had *something* to do with what Swift is doing with managing pointers here.

So, out of curiosity, I wanted to add a truly scalar value to the protocols.  I added a `value` property as an `Int` to the `TextPresentable` protocol:

```
protocol Presentable {}

protocol TextPresentable: Presentable {
    var text:String { get }
    var value: Int { get }
}

protocol ImagePresentable: Presentable {
    var image:String { get }
    var images:[String] { get }
}
```

And then I set up the concrete implementation to return some known value.  Here, we're returning `0`.

```
struct ConcretePresentable: TextPresentable, ImagePresentable {
    var text:String { return "SomeText" }
    var value: Int { return 0 }
    var image:String { return "SomeImage" }
    var images:[String] { return ["A", "B"] }
}
```

After running this code, we still get the same crash, but I notice that `value`, which really shouldn't have a problem printing `0` is instead printing some very large number: `4331676336`.  This isn't right at all.

I also changed `images` from an array to a dictionary to see if the error persists--it does.  It seems the crash is related to collections and not specific to arrays.

---

From here, I tried some other things.

I tried making `ConcretePresentable` a class rather than a struct.

```
class ConcretePresentable: TextPresentable, ImagePresentable
```

That resulted in the same behavior.

I tried making `ConcretePresentable` conform to the typealias rather than the protocols independently:

```
struct ConcretePresentable: TextAndImagePresentable
```

That resulted in the same behavior.

I tried doing both of the aforementioned at once:

```
class ConcretePresentable: TextAndImagePresentable
```

Yet still the same behavior.

---

I did come up with one way to make it work though.  Make a protocol that conforms to the two protocols in your `typealias` and make `ConcretePresentable` conform to that:

```
protocol TextAndImagePresentable: TextPresentable, ImagePresentable {}

struct ConcretePresentable: TextAndImagePresentable {
    // ...
}
```

The problem here is that if you don't explicitly make `ConcretePresentable` conform to the protocol, it will fail the `guard let` even if it does conform to `TextPresentable` and `ImagePresentable`.

Answer (score 1):

struct uses value semantics and so properties are copied. Swift should have reported this as an error since you are trying to inherit from two protocols which derive from the same base protocol. In classes this will work but in struct it wont because of value semantics for struct. In case you decide to add a variable to Presentable protocol Swift would be confused which ones to bring into the struct. From TextPresentable or ImagePresentable

You should use `@protocol Presentable : class` and then convert `ConcretePresentable` to class to fix this.

```
protocol Presentable : class {
}

class ConcretePresenter {...
```

Comment: There are two fairly big problems with this solution.  First of, changing your construct from a `struct` to a `class` can have pretty *major* implications throughout your application.  Second of, and perhaps the significantly bigger point here, is that `@objc` is only available if you are importing Foundation, so this simply isn't a solution for Linux at all.

Comment: About the first part, I guess there's nothing much because what is being tried seems to be semantically incorrect. Essentially multiple inheritance is being attempted on structs. Ideally Swift should have reported this as an error. Second point can be fixed by using class instead of @objc.

Comment: This happens even when the inheritance tree is simpler, i.e. when there's no common base protocol. Which makes me wonder what the cause of this problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the cast of the `Presentable` to `TextAndImagePresentable`. The `guard let` succeed, but creates an invalid value (I don't know exactly why).

One way to check it, is look to the console on the execution of the commands:

```
print(textAndImagePresentable.text)
print(textAndImagePresentable.image)
print(textAndImagePresentable.images)
```

That will print:

```
Image
Text
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

One way to avoid it is to change your method signature to avoid the casting:

```
func configureWithPresentable(presentable: TextAndImagePresentable) {
    print(presentable.text)
    print(presentable.image)
    print(presentable.images)
}
```

And, in my opinion, since nothing will happen if the `presentable` do not conform to both protocols, makes more sense to delimiter it on the method signature.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  This moves the problem.  You'd still be able to cast the struct, pass it in, and see the crash.  You'd just cast it before passing it in rather than after.